# How to combine 3 queries in 1

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a accounting table, from this table I monitoring the activity of the users. I have the 3 following queries:
First

```
select count(distinct username),
       DATE_FORMAT(StartTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
from acct
where date(starttime) = date '2014-10-02'
group by DATE_FORMAT(StartTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
```

Second

```
select count(distinct username),
       DATE_FORMAT(UpdateTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
from acct
where date(updatetime) = date '2014-10-02'
group by DATE_FORMAT(UpdateTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
```

Third

```
select count(distinct username),
       DATE_FORMAT(StopTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
from acct
where date(stoptime) = date '2014-10-02'
group by DATE_FORMAT(StopTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
```

I am little confused, it is possible to make them one query?I would like to check every hour of the day how many users is online. Can you guide me where to look to solve my problem?
Thanks

Fields starttime, updatetime and stoptime is datetime.

Comment: use `UNION` before the next `SELECT`

Comment: As @brewal said. Stick `union` or `union all` between each query and submit the whole big mess of sql. Your queries will be stuck together (`union` acts like a group by for all the results, where `union all` just stacks the results, duplicates and all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you grab the same amount of fields in all the select queries, you can then use `UNION`. But in that case, you might just want to use `OR` :

```
select COUNT(DISTINCT username) AS count_distinct_users,
       CASE WHEN date(StartTime) = date '2014-10-02' 
            THEN DATE_FORMAT(StartTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
            WHEN date(UpdateTime) = date '2014-10-02' 
            THEN DATE_FORMAT(UpdateTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
            WHEN date(StopTime) = date '2014-10-02' 
            THEN DATE_FORMAT(StopTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
       END AS date
from acct
where date(StartTime) = date '2014-10-02' 
or date(UpdateTime) = date '2014-10-02'
or date(StopTime) = date '2014-10-02'
group by date
```

**[sqlFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b5a27/1)**

Comment: In this case, it is possible to know which where clause is the true?

Comment: sorry, I forgot it ! you can use `case` for this

Comment: @KostasC I added a demo

Comment: Thanks @Brewal for your demo, but the starttime, updatetime and stoptime is datetime field. I would like to check every hour of the day how many users is online.

Comment: You should have said that in your question :]

Comment: I have updated the demo. It does not change anything to the query.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using the UNION:

```
select count(distinct username),
       DATE_FORMAT(StartTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
from acct
where date(starttime) = date '2014-10-02'
group by DATE_FORMAT(StartTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
UNION
select count(distinct username),
       DATE_FORMAT(UpdateTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
from acct
where date(updatetime) = date '2014-10-02'
group by DATE_FORMAT(UpdateTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
UNION
select count(distinct username),
       DATE_FORMAT(StopTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
from acct
where date(stoptime) = date '2014-10-02'
group by DATE_FORMAT(StopTime,'%H %d/%m/%y')
```

Comment: @jarlh:- Yes it can be but I thought to use UNION as I thought OP might not be interested in getting the duplicates. Hope that OP is aware of the difference between UNION and UNION ALL.